# How to disable month selection in Calendar

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm wondered how to disable the selection of the month in the calendar, if I click on in July as shown in the first image, it opens the selection of the month and continue with the selection of the year (see second image).
How can I disable this?

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is a ugly solution, but I think it can works: try putting a transparent rectangle over the month (`<RectangleName="rectHackngle" Stroke="Transparent" Panel.ZIndex="2" Fill="Transparent" />`) and set  the zIndex of the calendar to 1 (`Panel.ZIndex="1"`)

Answer (score 0):

Handle the event for changing the display mode, and if it's not in month mode then reset it back to being in month mode.

XAML:

```
<UserControls:MonthViewCalendar x:Name="schedCalendar" Grid.Row="1" DisplayModeChanged="MonthViewCalendar_DisplayModeChanged"/>
```

C# Code Behind for event handler

```
        private void MonthViewCalendar_DisplayModeChanged(object sender, CalendarModeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.NewMode != CalendarMode.Month)
            {
                schedCalendar.DisplayMode = e.OldMode;
            }
        }
```